# Can we set a process as the master/root process in MPI?

Tags: process, mpi, scanf

MPI seems to automatically designate 0 as the master process. But I want to be able to designate another process (e.g. process with rank 10) to be the master process.

Also, the function `scanf` only works in the master process: other processes simply ignore it and go to the next statement. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

You can create a separate *communicator* world subgroup with `MPI_Comm_create` or `MPI_Comm_split`.

As for `scanf`, I think, if you run them, say, on a different rank, it will output that rank process. Say, if you have a sperate terminal on that rank, but your terminal is most likely on rank 0, hence you only seeing the output there, but then your not running the program on the other ranks, so I don't think it will work.

To print from separate nodes you need to use `sprintf`, and store the result in memory, and then send it back to rank 0 to `printf` to your terminal.

Comment: But how do other processes can printf correctly if my terminal is on 0? And is there a way to open a new terminal for one of the other processes?

Comment: @user1464184 i think you would have to use `sprintf` to save the result to memory and then use `MPI_send` to send that back to rank 0 then print it out at rank 0, let me dig up an example

Comment: http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/teaching/AOS/NINE/mpi-first-examples.html  in example 4 that sprintf runs on every rank, but you can run it separately with a `if (rank = 3){ sprintf(....`

Answer (score 0):

When `mpiexec` starts MPI processes, only one of them receives `stdin`.  The rest will not have that descriptor open, so reading from it will just return an error.  If you check the return value from `scanf` it will probably be `EOF`.  Technically there could be an implementation that would copy the contents of `stdin` and forward to all processes, but I don't think any MPI does this.

`stdout` on the other hand is usually collected from all processes by the launcher, and printed on the terminal, but the order in which things get printed is next to impossible to control.  The common solution is to collect the data at one rank manually and have it print everything, as pyCthon suggested.

Finally, OpenMPI's `mpiexec` can do the things you asked for: specify which rank will get `stdin`, and even launch certain ranks in a separate `xterm`.  This might be useful for debugging, but I wouldn't rely on these features for core functionality: you might want to use your code with a different MPI implementation some day.  Besides, say you are running on a large cluster - do you really want a thousand terminals open? :)